# μF not working in Latex

Tags: symbols

Have been using below code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \si{\um}
\end{document}
```

to represent `μm` but similarly, `\si{\uF}` not working for `μF`. So, how can I get the symbol for `μF` ?

Comment: Did you already try with \micro\farad?

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot. It worked

Comment: @leandriis you can answer so that I can select for further reference

Comment: Without `siunitx` help ... micro is the Greek letter `$\mu$` and you can always use it like this in math mode ... TeX has internal support for such characters...

Comment: @koleygr That will come out italic, which is wrong

Comment: @JosephWright ... It will be italic, but the whole (La)TeX uses math this way ... It is wrong to combine with `siunitx` that by default used upright font for some reasons that we will not analyze here ... Anyway ... Thanks for mentioning ... I just didn't proposed combination with `siunitx` way of units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get `μF`, use `\si{\micro\farad}`.

`\um` for `μm` only works because it is defined as a shortcut by siunitx. For a full list of all available shortcut see table 21 in the siunitx manual.